# How to correctly scroll after item inserted into PagedListAdapter

Tags: android-paging

I am using the Android Arch `PagedListAdapter` class. The issue I have run into is that since my app is a chat style app, I need to scroll to position 0 when an item is inserted. But the PagedListAdapter finds the diffs and calls necessary methods on the background thread so it seems that there is no dependable way to call `layoutManager.scrollToPosition(0)`

If anyone has any ideas on how I could scroll at the right time, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Here is my Room Dao:

```
@Dao
abstract class MessagesDao {

    @Query("SELECT ...")
    abstract fun getConversation(threadId: String): DataSource.Factory<Int, Conversation>

}
```

and then the LivePagedListBuilder:

```
LivePagedListBuilder(database.messagesDao.getConversation(threadId), PagedList.Config.Builder()
            .setInitialLoadSizeHint(20)
            .setPageSize(12)
            .setEnablePlaceholders(true)
            .build()).build()
```

Comment: Can you provide tour DataSource Implementation? How you use real-time data source with PagedList?

Comment: @KeivanEsbati I have edited the question with that info. I used Room Database

Comment: @NickMowen how did u reversed the pagedList to have position 0 at the bottom?

Comment: @AlexAndro yes I did

Comment: @NickMowen I'm sure you did. Can you please share `HOW` did you do that?

Comment: @AlexAndro just set the reverse layout flag on the layout manager constructor.. it's a simple Google for that one

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It turns out that there is this beautiful thing called AdapterDataObsever which lets you observe the PagedListAdapter item calls. Here is how I was able to use it to solve the problem.

```
conversationAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(object : RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
        override fun onItemRangeInserted(positionStart: Int, itemCount: Int) {
            if (positionStart == 0) {
                manager.scrollToPosition(0)
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. The callback is invoked but the RecyclerView doesn't change position. Any idea what might cause this?

Comment: @masterwok If you don't have placeholders enabled and scroll to a position which isn't currently loaded it will not scroll

Comment: Hi @NickMowen thank you for your feedback. What ended up working for me is I implemented all of the *onItem* change listeners AND enabled placeholders. Thank you.